# Confused about DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I am retrieving a few bunches of int/string pairs that I want to generate dropdown lists for, and subsequently use these filter a collection of items.

Currently, I create these filters as SelectLists in the Controller this way:

```
foreach (int key in filterChoices.Keys)
                subFilter.Add(new SelectListItem {Value = key.ToString(), Text = filterChoices[key]});
```

where "filterChoices" holds the id (int) and text (string) as key, value pairs.

Then I'm a bit confused as to what to do. I have tried to put together bits and pieces from various examples, but don't really understand what's going on.

This is what I'm trying currently:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDimension, new SelectList(Model.DimensionFilter, "Text", "Value", Model.DimensionFilter.First().Text));
```

The first part, I'm not really sure what its use is, but I am assuming it's the property whose change controls what is being selected in the list? Something along those lines? So I'm trying to set this int to some arbitrary value that corresponds to one filter entry, but to no avail.

No DropDown shows up.

Comment: The first past of the dropdownlistfor is the property that holds the value of the selected item. The second part is the list of items (SelectedListItem). Instead of creating a new selectlist in the view you should put it in the controller and then pass it to the view, easier for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDimension, Model.DimensionFilter)
```

if you already created a selectList

Comment: Oh, thanks. That looks way cleaner.

There is still no DropDown showing though. I guess I am using the SelectedDimension property wrong. I should be able to initialize it to whichever "Value" from the list, right?

Comment: Hehe, I sort of forgot to use the @ before the Html.DropDownListFor. Still new to MVC...